# Map multiple query parameters in jax-rs

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am using Jersey as the implementation library.

```
@Path("books")
public class Sample {

    @GET
    public List<Book> getBooks(@Context UriInfo uriInfo)
    {
        MultivaluedMap<String,String> params = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
        String pageStart = params.getFirst("p");
        String pageSize = params.getFirst("s");
    }
}
```

It works fine with /books but doesn't work for /books?p=1&s=10 (http 404 error)

I don't want to define my path like "books?p={p}&s={s}" since there will be dynamic parameters that cannot be predefined.

question:

Is there any way that i can map /books?p=1&s=10 to the getBooks method??

Comment: try to add `@Path("/")` annotation to the method itself

Answer (score 0):

can check by having you `@Path("books")` changed to `@Path("/books")`